# excel vba for loop not working

Tags: excel, vba, loops

```
Sub change2()
    Dim area As Range
    Dim seconds As Range
    Dim Teller As Integer
    Dim number As Integer

    Set area = Range("M6:M79")

    number = 70

    For Teller = 1 To number
        If seconds.Cells(Teller) > 44 Then
            seconds.Cells(Teller).Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            seconds.Cells(Teller).Font.Color = vbBlue
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I get the error

> object variable or with block variable not set.

I believe I am not correctly addressing the cells, I want it to loop through the cells, and if the number is less than 44 in the area then turn red otherwise turn blue. The values in the area is from 1 to 70

Comment: Do you mean to have the `If` statement on the same line as `For`? (That would make a difference in VBA).

Comment: @Bathsheba - if you view their question through the editor, it looks like it's on a separate line, it just got formatted wonky in the editor.

Comment: Great. Wanted to eliminate that before rushing in with the answer.

Comment: @Bjørn Vidar - if you're just changing the font color, why not use Conditional Formatting instead of going to all that effort to write a VBA script?

Comment: It´s of course for a school assignment. Otherwise I used for each before with great success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors with your code:

1. When you put `seconds` in front of `Cells` you are referencing a worksheet.  You need to `Dim seconds As Worksheet` and then `Set seconds = Sheets("Sheet Name")`
2. The proper syntax for `Cells()` is `Cells(rowindex, colindex)`  Your loop only has ONE number which I assume is Rows, so you would need to use `seconds.Cells(Teller, NUMBER OF COLUMN)`
3. When you want to find out what is in a cell, the syntax is `Cells().Value`.  So your complete syntax after defining what sheet the `seconds` variable is would be `seconds.Cells(Teller, NUMBER OF COLUMN).Value > 44`
4. Why do you define an `area` variable?  Seems to serve no purpose in your code.

Comment: I will test this straight away

Answer (score 1):

You don't ever assign `seconds` to anything.

Its referring to `Nothing` is the cause of your runtime error.